# Python program Convert middle digits into its corresponding alphabets form in between start position and end position

Tags: python-3.8

take string and two integers from user and convert middle digits into its corresponding alphabetical form in between start and end position

```
def convert_digits( input_string, start_position, end_position ) :
    new_string = input_string[:start_position]
    digit_mapping = {
        '0': 'ZERO',
        '1': 'ONE',
        '2': 'TWO',
        '3': 'THREE',
        '4': 'FOUR',
        '5': 'FIVE',    
        '6': 'SIX',
        '7': 'SEVEN',
        '8': 'EIGHT',
        '9': 'NINE'
    }
    
    for index in range(start_position, end_position):
        if input_string[index].isdigit():
            mapped = digit_mapping[input_string[index]]
            new_string = mapped
        
    new_string += input_string[end_position + 1:]
    return new_string
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def convert_digits(input_string, start_position, end_position):
    len_str = len(input_string)
    if end_position > len_str:
        end_position = len_str
    if start_position < 0:
        start_position = 0
    elif start_position >= end_position:
        start_position = end_position - 1
    input_string = input_string[start_position:end_position]
    digit_mapping = {
        '0': 'ZERO',
        '1': 'ONE',
        '2': 'TWO',
        '3': 'THREE',
        '4': 'FOUR',
        '5': 'FIVE',
        '6': 'SIX',
        '7': 'SEVEN',
        '8': 'EIGHT',
        '9': 'NINE'
    }
    input_string = list(input_string)
    for index, char in enumerate(input_string):
        if char.isdigit():
            input_string[index] = digit_mapping[char]
    return "".join(input_string)


print(convert_digits("ajoegh12ioh12oih", 0, 14))
```